# BuildMethodException: [GoogleMobileAds] Neither Ad Manager nor AdMob is enabled yet

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, admob

BuildMethodException: [GoogleMobileAds] Neither Ad Manager nor AdMob is enabled yet.
ManifestProcessor.StopBuildWithMessage (System.String message).

Help me i make new android game in unity...Add (Banner Ad) in Google admob in unity 
I want to build this game Because of this Error, I can't be build this game..

Comment: Enable GoogleMobileAdsSettings.Instance.IsAdManagerEnabled and GoogleMobileAdsSettings.Instance.IsAdMobEnabled properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assets-> GoogleMob Ads-> Setting & add app id below

Answer (score 0):

Assets-> GoogleMobileAds-> Resources -> GoogleMobileAdsSettings